# RadGrid -- Not able to edit all rows except last row

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I am able to edit (double click) only the last row in a RadGrid. When I select any other row it throws an error.

> There was a problem extracting DataKeyValues from the DataSource. Please ensure that DataKeyNames are specified correctly and all fields specified exist in the DataSource.

Has anyone faced this problem? If I'm able to edit one row why not others?

Comment: It's Row ? Not column ? And can you show me your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `dataKeyNames`  in your `MasterTableView` .
For Example , if your table has three columns(`Column1,Column2,Column3`)

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
  <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Column1,Column2,Column3">  
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```